# Issue with pivot table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, pivot-table

I have problem with pivot table in Laravel, 
I made `customers` and `products` tables and `customer_product` table to connect this two but it isn't working. 
Below I add this pivot table

```
    Schema::create('customer_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('customer_id');
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
        $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->decimal('selling_customer_price');
        $table->decimal('purchase_customer_price'); 
        $table->decimal('consumed_customer_price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Part of my ProductController where I list products and I want show customers products

```
public function list()
{

    return view('products.list', [
        'customers' => Customer::all(),
        'products' => Product::orderby('name')->get(),

    ]);
}
```

and part of simple blade code

```
<div>
     @foreach ($customers as $customer)
        <li> {{ $customer->name }} {{ $customer->products }} </li>
     @endforeach
</div>
```

part of Product class

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class);
}
```

and part of Customers class

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

when I type list site I have error about lack of `customer_id` column in `product` table but I want use my pivot table because I have to use different prices to different customers.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'products.customer_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `products` where `products`.`customer_id` = 1 and
>   `products`.`customer_id` is not null) (View:
>   /home/vagrant/code/resources/views/products/list.blade.php)

Comment: The SQL error suggest you forget to update the products schema with a customer_id column...  Is the table `customer_product` correctly created? Because `$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');` should fail.. Assuming the mysql's default engine is InnoDB which only supports foreign keys.

Comment: Does the customer_id field is present in your products table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you have many to many relation then you should have relation like below and from your comments, you have `selling_customer_price` field in pivot table for that you have to use  `withPivot`. For details check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

part of Product class

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class)->withPivot('selling_customer_price');
}
```

and part of Customers class

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('selling_customer_price');
}
```

Then fetch it like this

```
public function list()
{

    return view('products.list', [
        'customers' => Customer::with('products')->all(),
        'products' => Product::orderby('name')->get(),

    ]);
}
```

In view

```
<div>
      <ul>
        @foreach ($customers as $customer)
          <li> {{ $customer->name }} </li>
          <ul>
            @foreach ($customer->products as $product)
                <li> {{ $product->name }} </li>
                <li> {{ $product->pivot->selling_customer_price }} </li>
            @endforeach
          </ul>
        @endforeach
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, I didn't remember use belongsToMany in both class, Your post is very helpfull for me.

Comment: add your issue in question, not in answer

Comment: I have one more issue because this show information about product connected with customer pivot table but I add selling_customer_price in this pivot table. I have question is it possible to get info from this cell or this is bad idea to store customer special price?

$table->decimal('selling_customer_price');

Comment: @azbroja updated answer with `selling_customer_price` in pivot check it

Comment: if it works then you can accept it as answer and upvote for future visiting user

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Ok, Like you see I'am newbie thank you once again, I thick green check mark :)